# Module scikit_learn not defined in spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I run this module in Visual Studio Code editor.But in Spider IDE i get error . Module not defined in Spider IDE. I use pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because you are probably using conda environment in Spider, which does not have the sklearn installed.

You will want to do a `conda install -c intel scikit-learn`
Or, if you have anaconda, just installed it from anaconda environment. If that does not work, try using pip. But since it works in vs code for you, I think conda environment is the cause.

If you are not using conda environment, I think you might have multi python environment. Then, you can do a `pip install scikit-learn` with the python you are using with the spyder. Or you can set the spyder interpreter as the same as the one you used in vscode.

Comment: but i dont use anconda